# Is there a current method of indicating to users that a link won't take them off site?

Tags: user-experience

It's currently impossible for a user to tell if clicking on something will load something in their current page or take them to a new page. I feel that this is why many sites use hoverable dropdown menus, so that they don't have to click anything. This can be messy, though, if you don't intentionally hover over something and forms the habit of hovering over things and expecting a result.

There should be a standard way to identify links as external or internal. Maybe a little hover effect or symbol used in the link?

Is there anything like this, and if not, should there be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe by "internal" you mean that the link does some javascript thing, and does not load a new page.

I think an effective way to indicate an immediate action is by using a button style, rather than a standard looking link. A blue underlined link somehow seems much more likely to jump to a new page than something that looks like a button.

Give the button an appropriate label and/or symbol that indicates an instant action. For example, a button that expands a section open might use a little triangle that rotates as the expanding happens.

You can also establish a consistent style for "internal" actions, use a particular color or style for links that don't take the user to a new page. Sometimes I use blue for normal links and a shade of purple for internal ones.

In general, I find it isn't that important to specify. If a user sees a link or button that like it will get them what they want, they will click it. It is up to you as the designer of the website to decide if the most appropriate action is a new page, or an action on the current page. Unless the user is going to lose some work they have done, going to a new page shouldn't be a problem. If it really took the user by surprise, they can always go back. In my experience, users don't worry about it either way.

Comment: And if you really did mean "off the site", there is a little arrow in a box symbol I've seen that represents this, but the user could always look at the status bar to see where the link goes.